# What is the difference between total follow-up time and time to death (in years)?

Tags: survival

In epidemiology, what is the difference between total follow-up time and time to death (in years)? Examples would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Time to death is right censored (you will observe some people dying, but lots of people in your study you will stop tracking before they die so you don't know their time to death). Total follow up time is the total time that a person is tracked.